# Importing a C library into a Swift project

Tags: ios, c, xcode, swift

I am trying to import libsass (a C library) into my OSX project written in Swift. But somehow I am dealing with a lot of dependency problems. Btw I am using the **Module maps** method in this guide here: https://spin.atomicobject.com/2015/02/23/c-libraries-swift/.

---

**libsass repo: https://github.com/sass/libsass**

I am able to run a version.c(example libsass provided) program in c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "sass/context.h"
int main() {
  puts(libsass_version());
  return 0;
}
```

My approach was to import the header files in the 'libsass/include' directory.

**Here is what a tried so far:**

**1** I built a module.map file and place it in the libsass directory.

```
module libsass [system] {
    header "include/sass.h"
    export *
}
```

**2** I then add the directory into my swift project

**3** setting Swift Compiler > Search Paths > Import Paths to '${SRCROOT}/libsass'

**4** build and I encounter this:

```
'sass/base.h' file not found with <angled> include; use "quotes" instead
'sass/version.h' file not found with <angled> include; use "quotes" instead
'sass/values.h' file not found with <angled> include; use "quotes" instead
```

**5** Build settings > Search Paths > Header Search Paths set to '$(PROJECT_DIR)/libsass/include'

Build settings > Search Paths > Library Search Paths set to '$(PROJECT_DIR)/libsass/include'

this time I don't see previous errors but encountered a new error in test_superselector.cpp:

```
'../ast.hpp' file not found
```

**6**
I added '-lsass' to Build settings > Linking > Other Linker Flags. Since in the example that the libsass provided, they uses the -lsass flag to compile the c code.

Same, no good.

I spent two days trying to figure this out but no clear progress. Please take a look into the libsass repo. Any helps are appreciated. **Thanks!!**

Answer (score 0):

I briefly looked at the libsass code on github. The `ast.hpp` file cannot be found because you must have added the libsass source directory to your Xcode project and it is trying to build the library source as part of the project.

Since you added `-lsass` to your linker flags, I think you are trying to use an already built library in your project, which is a cleaner approach and that's where module maps are useful.

You should not add libsass directories to your Xcode project.  You can place the directories containing libsass headers and the library within your project's directory, which is not the same as adding them to your project.

The `header` line in `module.map` should have the header's absolute path or path relative to the location of `module.map`.

A few other observations:

- Library Search Paths should contain the directory where the `libsass`
  library file is located.  For example, if it is a static library,
  then the file would be called `libsass.a`.
- From looking at the library source, it is a C++ library, so you won't
  be able to use it directly in Swift; wrappers would be necessary,
  written in Objective-C++, for example.